# Python if-condition import json file base on different column values

Tags: python, json, if-statement

I'd like to import different JSON format file based on a csv's column('type' column) values, JSON file is used to parse data from csv. Finally the csv would be transformed to JSON format.

Different type needs different JSON format file, so I'd like to import several JSON file to do the paring.

Please find the csv format:

```
type date name  ...
aaa   1   Jay
bbb   2   Jenny
ccc   3   Lucy
...
```

And codes:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fp = './data.csv'
    if fp[fp['type'] == 'aaa'] or fp[fp['type'] == 'bbb']:
       format_fp = './type1_format.json'
    elif fp[fp['type'] == 'ccc']:
        format_fp = './type3_format.json'
```

but error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Question: How could I import and use different json format file based on different type?

Many thanks!

Comment: It throws a `TypeError` because in the statement `fp[fp['type'] == '1']`, `fp['type'] == '1'` returns a `boolean` and not an iteger.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the native python `csv` package.

Using dict reader you could do something like this:

```
with open('./data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['type'] == 'aaa' or row['type'] == 'bbb':
            format_fp = './type1_format.json'
        elif row['type'] == 'ccc':
            format_fp = './type3_format.json'
```

This will iterate through each row in the csv file and let you do whatever it is you want to do with the JSON files on a row by row basis. You can reference the other columns with `row['date']` and `row['name']` etc.

OLD COMMENT

`fp = './data.csv'` does not import a csv file.

From the rest of the code it seems likely that you are trying to import it using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), for which you'll need to `import pandas` and use `fp = pandas.read_csv('./data.csv')`

Though even once you have imported the files `fp[fp['type'] == '1']` will return a subset of the dataframe, not a true or false value, so your code likely won't work as intended either.

If you give some more detail about what data.csv contains, and exactly what your goal is, we might be able to provide more assistance.

Comment: Hi thanks!, I have edited my question, basically I'd like to use different JSON file to parse csv data to JSON format based on the type.

Comment: @Joyce I've updated my response, hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but when testing with the codes, it throw 'invalid syntax' error in line 'if'